# Additional line in block vs additional parameter in Clean Code

Tags: clean-code, solid

### Context

In *Clean Code*, page 35, it says

> This implies that the blocks within if statements, else statements,
>   while statements, and so on should be one line long. Probably that
>   line should be a function call. Not only does this keep the enclosing
>   function small, but it also adds documentary value because the
>   function called within the block can have a nicely descriptive name.

I completely concur, that makes a lot of sense.

Later on, on page 40, it says about function arguments

> The ideal number of arguments for a function is zero (niladic). Next
>   comes one (monadic), followed closely by two (dyadic). Three arguments
>   (triadic) should be avoided where possible. More than three (polyadic)
>   requires very special justification—and then shouldn’t be used anyway.
>   Arguments are hard. They take a lot of conceptual power.

I completely concur, that makes a lot of sense.

### Issue

However, rather often I find myself creating a list from another list and I will have to live with one of two evils.

Either I **use two lines in the block**, one for creating the thing, one for adding it to the result:

```
    public List<Flurp> CreateFlurps(List<BadaBoom> badaBooms)
    {
        List<Flurp> flurps = new List<Flurp>();
        foreach (BadaBoom badaBoom in badaBooms)
        {
            Flurp flurp = CreateFlurp(badaBoom);
            flurps.Add(flurp);
        }
        return flurps;
    }
```

Or I **add an argument to the function** for the list where the thing will be added to, making it "one argument worse".

```
    public List<Flurp> CreateFlurps(List<BadaBoom> badaBooms)
    {
        List<Flurp> flurps = new List<Flurp>();
        foreach (BadaBoom badaBoom in badaBooms)
        {
            CreateFlurpInList(badaBoom, flurps);
        }
        return flurps;
    }
```

### Question

Are there (dis-)advantages I am not seeing, which make one of them preferable in general? Or are there such advantages in certain situations; in that case, what should I look for when making a decision?

Comment: What's wrong with `flurps.Add(CreateFlurp(badaBoom));`?

Comment: @cmaster It's two statements in one line, which is more difficult to debug. However, we discussed this in David Arno's answer and the solution is you have to write code which doesn't need to be debugged.

Comment: Nope, it's just a single statement. It's just a trivially nested **expression** (a single nested level). And if a simple `f(g(x))` is against your style-guide, well, I can't fix your style-guide. I mean, you don't split `sqrt(x*x + y*y)` into four lines either, do you? And that's three(!) nested subexpressions on two(!) inner nesting levels (gasp!). Your goal should be **readability**, not single operator statements. If you want the later, well, I have the perfect language for you: Assembler.

Comment: @cmaster Even x86 assembly doesn't strictly have single-operator statements. The memory addressing modes include many complicated operations and can be used for arithmetic - in fact, you can make a Turing-complete computer using only x86 `mov` instructions and a single `jmp toStart` at the end. Someone actually made a compiler that does exactly that :D

Comment: @Luaan Not to speak of the infamous `rlwimi` instruction on the PPC. (That stands for Rotate Left Word Immediate Mask Insert.) This command took no less than five operands (two registers, and three immediate values), and it performed the following operations: One register contents was rotated by an immediate shift, a mask was created with a single run of 1 bits which was controlled by the two other immediate operands, and the bits that corresponded to 1 bits in that mask in the other register operand were replaced with the corresponding bits of the rotated register. Very cool instruction :-)

Comment: @cmaster You're doing math and that might work out fine for you, but Im doing general purpose programming. I have a 120 columns limit in my IDE. I give my variables descriptive names, which can be 3 words together without breaking a sweat - not a single letter. On average, your example wouldn't even *fit* into a single line. So, to answer your question: Yes, I would split it. And I would do it for **readability**. However, this completely misses the point, which was that *an error in Add() or CreateFlurp() wold both point to the same line number*.

Comment: @R.Schmitz "Im doing general purpose programming"--actually no, you're not, you're doing programming for a specific purpose (I don't know *what* purpose, but I'm assuming *you* do ;-). There are literally thousands of purposes for programming, and the optimal coding styles for them vary--so what is appropriate for you may not be suitable for others, and vice versa: Often advice here is absolute ("*always* do X; Y is *bad*" etc) ignoring that in some domains it's utterly impractical to stick to. That's why advice in books like Clean Code should always be taken with a pinch of (practical) salt:)

Comment: I'm puzzled: If there's an error in `Add()`, you'd get a stack trace identifying the call, no? Same story for `CreateFlurp()`. Anyway, "I have a 120 columns limit in my IDE", that's one of your problems right there. I've long since come to the conclusion that **any** line length limit will at times conflict with a legit statement. "Fixing" that by splitting legit lines is like constructing a better bypass to a broken motorway instead of fixing the motorway. Kick the line length limit, and you will be much more relaxed. (Even Fortran allows 132 characters, nowadays, and that's still a PITA.)

Comment: @cmaster If I get a NRE for `flurps.Add(_flurpCreator.Create())`, that can be two things, opposed to one. Concerning the line limit, I have my code screen in portrait mode, you know what really relaxes me? When I don't have to *scroll sideways* [SHUDDER]. If you're looking at this on a computer, look at the left and right of this very text. There's a lot of whitespace, because they dun the research and the result was that 140+ character lines have nothing to do with readability anymore.

Comment: Re: readability and line lengths (part 1): It's worth considering that newspapers, magazines, text-books, and similar print media that have ample horizontal space to work with pretty much universally word wrap at a little over 60 characters (bearing in mind that they're not monospaced and have fancy kerning algorithms, so they don't have a strict number of character "columns" per line per se).

Comment: Re: readability and line lengths (part 2): Breaking up lines to an arbitrary line limit *is* often frustrating and requires convolutions that a single line would not. Especially in combination with really descriptive names for things, which I strive for. And I subject myself to a 79-character limit, so I feel this pain regularly. That said, in my personal experience as both a developer and a system admin, I've found that, on average across all the mediums I have to look at code in, I am impeded by long lines more than I am benefited by them.

Comment: My solution to the long line problem is to simply switch on soft wrapping in the editor. No horizontal scrolling necessary, the full width of the window is utilized, whatever that may be, and continued lines stand out clearly in properly indented text. Don't get me wrong, I'm not saying that that you shouldn't strive for sensible line lengths on average. Most lines should be shorter than 80 characters. But there's always the exceptions: Any line length limit will both allow for too long lines and force you to break lines that you shouldn't break at the same time. There is no sensible limit.

Comment: @cmaster - Try submitting code to python. They'll come down hard on you if your code doesn't live within Guido's 79 character limit. Try submitting code to the projects where I'm the king, or have advisory input to the king. We'll come down hard on you of your code doesn't live within our slightly more generous 80 character limit. I **hate** long lines. (And "hate" isn't quite strong enough.) The compiler/interpreter could care less about line length. The  reasons for keeping lines short is entirely because people, not machines, will be reading your code.

Comment: Yes, there are always exceptions. For example, `#include "a/path/that/is/too/long/to/fit/within/80/chars.hh"`. Fine, there are exceptions. That doesn't mean you shouldn't have a rule.

Comment: @cmaster: Re `sqrt(x*x + y*y)`. That's a bad example. You should be using `hypot(x,y)`. That it's shorter to write is an extremely minor benefit. Much more importantly, `hypot` avoids overflow, underflow, and truncation errors.

Comment: @DavidHammen When you are working for a project that has a style guide, you need to follow that style guide, at least in spirit. I know that there are a lot of style guides that contain stupid rules (like linux with 80 characters line limit plus no tabs plus eight space indentation...), but when my goal is to get code accepted, I need to follow the rules, even if I don't like them. That won't stop me from saying that those rules are harmful, though.

Answer (score 106, accepted):

These guidelines are a compass, not a map. They point you in a sensible *direction*. But they can't really tell you in absolute terms which solution is “best”. At some point, you need to stop walking into the direction your compass is pointing, because you have arrived at your destination.

Clean Code encourages you to divide your code into very small, obvious blocks. That is a generally good direction. But when taken to the extreme (as a literal interpretation of the quoted advice suggests), then you will have subdivided your code into uselessly small pieces. Nothing really does anything, everything just delegates. This is essentially another kind of code obfuscation.

It is your job to balance “smaller is better” against “too small is useless”. Ask yourself which solution is simpler. For me, that is clearly the first solution as it *obviously* assembles a list. This is a well-understood idiom. It is possible to understand that code without having to look at yet another function.

If it's possible to do better, it's by noting that “transform all elements from a list to another list” is a common pattern that can often be abstracted away, by using a functional `map()` operation. In C#, I think it's called `Select`. Something like this:

```
public List<Flurp> CreateFlurps(List<BadaBoom> badaBooms)
{
    return badaBooms.Select(BadaBoom => CreateFlurp(badaBoom)).ToList();
}
```

Comment: The code is still wrong, and it pointlessly reinvents the wheel.  Why call `CreateFlurps(someList)` when the BCL already provides `someList.ConvertAll(CreateFlurp)` ?

Comment: @BenVoigt This is a design-level question. I'm unconcerned with exact syntax, especially since *a whiteboard doesn't have a compiler* (and I have last written C# in '09). My point is not “I've shown the best possible code” but “as an aside, this is a common pattern that's already solved”. Linq is one way to do it, the ConvertAll you mention [another](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TIMTOWTDI). Thank you for suggesting that alternative.

Comment: Your answer is sensible, but the fact that LINQ abstracts the logic away and reduces the statement to one line after all seems to contradict your advice. As a side note, `BadaBoom => CreateFlurp(badaBoom)` is redundant; you can pass `CreateFlurp` as the function directly (`Select(CreateFlurp)`). (As far as I know, this has always been the case.)

Comment: Note that this removes the need for the method entirely.  The name `CreateFlurps` is actually more misleading and harder to understand than just seeing `badaBooms.Select(CreateFlurp)`.  The latter is completely declarative -- there's no problem to decompose and therefore no need for a method at all.

Comment: @Carl Leth My explanation of what it does would be "I have a list of BadaBooms and create `Flurps` from them". I don't see how a method that takes a `List<BadaBoom>`, returns a `List<Flurp>` and is called `CreateFlurps` is misleading and/or hard to understand. Honestly, the English word 'Select' makes less sense in that context.

Comment: @R.Schmitz It's not _hard_ to understand, but it's _less easy_ to understand than `badaBooms.Select(CreateFlurp)`.  You create a method so that its name (high level) stands in for its implementation (low level).  In this case they're at the same level, so to find out exactly what's happening I have to just go look at the method (instead of seeing it inline).  `CreateFlurps(badaBooms)` could hold surprises, but `badaBooms.Select(CreateFlurp)` cannot.  It's also misleading because it's erroneously asking for a `List` instead of an `IEnumerable`.

Answer (score 62):

> The ideal number of arguments for a function is zero (niladic)

No! The ideal number of arguments for a function is one. If it's zero, then you are guaranteeing that the function has to access external information to be able to perform an action. "Uncle" Bob got this one very wrong.

Regarding your code, your first example only has two lines in the block because you are creating a local variable on the first line. Remove that assignment, and you are complying with these clean code guidelines:

```
public List<Flurp> CreateFlurps(List<BadaBoom> badaBooms)
{
    List<Flurp> flurps = new List<Flurp>();
    foreach (BadaBoom badaBoom in badaBooms)
    {
        flurps.Add(CreateFlurp(badaBoom));
    }
    return flurps;
}
```

But that's very long winded (C#) code. Just do it as:

```
IEnumerable<Flurp> CreateFlurps(IEnumerable<BadaBoom> badaBooms) =>
    from badaBoom in babaBooms select CreateFlurp(badaBoom);
```

Comment: A function with zero arguments is meant to imply the object encapsulates the required data not that things are existing in a global state outside an object.

Comment: @Ryathal, two points: (1) if you are talking methods, then for most (all?) OO languages, that object is inferred (or explicitly stated, in the case of Python) as the first parameter. In Java, C# etc, all methods are functions with at least one parameter. The compiler just hides that detail from you. (2) I never mentioned "global". The object state is external to a method for example.

Comment: I think the guy is well aware that the object is passed as "this" or "self" parameter. It is just written in a way that doesn't confuse beginners. People who *are* aware of the hidden first parameter will have no problem doing a mental "+1", but even they will probably prefer to discuss it that way - at least that's the case for me.

Comment: Now, about your actual answer, it is putting 2 statements on one line. I avoid doing that for debugging reasons. I see how in the example I chose - with a `List` - there's not much benefit to that, but it might be a custom class instead of a `List`. Anyway, that doesn't really matter, you did answer the question as it was posed and it is a nice explanation.

Comment: Im am pretty sure, when Uncle Bob wrote "zero" he meant "zero (not counting this)".

Comment: @DocBrown, probably as he's a big fan of mixing state and functionality in objects, so by "function" he likely refers specifically to methods. And I still disagree with him. It's far better to only give a method what it needs, rather than leave it rummage through the object to obtain what it wants (ie, it's classic "tell, don't ask" in action).

Comment: @R.Schmitz, rather than "writing code that's easier to debug", I opt for "writing code that doesn't need debugging".

Comment: The ideal is less parameters as possible, ergo 0 is better than 1. If you cannot get the job done with 0 use 1.

Comment: @AlessandroTeruzzi, The ideal is one parameter. Zero is too few. This is why, for example, functional languages adopt one as the number of parameters for currying purposes (in fact in some functional languages, all functions have exactly one parameter: no more; no less). Currying with zero parameters would be nonsensical. Stating that "the ideal is as few as possible, ergo zero is best" is an example of *reductio ad absurdum*.

Comment: @David Arno Actually, after thinking about this for a while, a hypothetical static `GetRandomFloat()` function would work well with *actually* zero arguments. That's really an edge case, but one does only need one counter example to disprove a statement.

Comment: @R.Schmitz, `GetRandomFloat()` presumably gets a random value each time its called? If so, that is the worst possible use of a static function as it's the complete opposite of a deterministic one. I'd definitely want it to be an instance method, belonging to a class with a seed etc, so that I can create completely deterministic pseudo-random sequences for testing purposes for example. So it needs at least one parameter: `this`. Sorry, but my statement stands. ;)

Comment: Arguably the closest thing to a "functional" random-value-getter would involve some sort of monad representing the external potentially non-deterministic source of random numbers, so there's definitely effectively an argument either implicitly or explicitly involved, and mainstream programming languages that just hide that detail from you are just implicitly accessing something global.

Comment: @AlessandroTeruzzi - Re *The ideal is less parameters as possible, ergo 0 is better than 1.* That's a logical fallacy. Just because one argument is "better" than one hundred (okay, I'll agree with that) does not mean that zero arguments is better than one.

Comment: @DavidArno a private function should use 0 arguments, because as stated before the object should encapsulate the required data to work within itself. A public function is perfectly fine with 1 argument as it possibly requires external data to work with and/or transform into something else

Comment: @JoshPart, as above: "*It's far better to only give a method what it needs, rather than leave it rummage through the object to obtain what it wants (ie, it's classic "tell, don't ask" in action)*". This specifically refers to private functions. Obviously, if a private method needs significant access to the object's state (such that more than 3-4 parameters would be needed), then give it `this`, ie give it zero parameters.

Comment: @JoshPart Ew, no! If you need to call a private method, and it needs some extra information to configure what it does, passing that information in via parameters is **far** superior to adding an extra fields to the class to hold that information instead. It usually makes code *less* clear to take a method of "too many parameters" and get rid of some by adding fields to the object that have to be initialised before the call. I would go so far as to disagree that "fewer is better" is a general rule to nearly always follow; the "best" number is small, but very context-dependent.

Comment: I don't know that 1 is ideal. How could you add two numbers if all operations were unary? Also, `badaBooms.Select(CreateFlurp)` is much better than all that verbose LINQ to SQL.

Comment: @jpmc26 Potentially via currying, as mentioned above.

Comment: @jpmc26 I think you're confusing _LINQ to SQL_ with _query syntax_.

Comment: @Zano It appears I have; I thought that was the name. Thanks.

Comment: @Carcigenicate I think currying is something of a slight of hand. You still need binary operations *somewhere*, whether they're encoded inside a function that's curried or somewhere else. Looking at [Wikipedia's example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying#Partial_application), you can see that the binary operations are just hidden inside other functions. This makes me think that maybe the ideal is 1 *or* 2.

Comment: @jpmc26, "the ideal is 1" is a hypothetical ideal; it's an aspiration. It's just another way of saying "keep your parameters to a minimum (excluding zero)". Clearly, eg in your example, some functions make no sense without two parameters. If you have two parameters, I'm not saying your function is somehow wrong. However, I do think you completely wrong re favouring extension methods over the elegant beauty of linq query syntax. ;)

Comment: @DavidArno the `GetRandomFloat()` function is totally deterministic. - as long as you use this version: https://xkcd.com/221/

Comment: @Baldrickk, XKCD as brilliant as ever! :)

Answer (score 20):

The 'Clean Code' Advice is completely wrong.

Use two or more lines in your loop. Hiding the same two lines in a function makes sense when they are some random maths which needs a description but it does nothing when the lines are already descriptive. 'Create' and 'Add'

The second method you mention in doesn't really make any sense, as you are not forced to add a second argument in order to avoid the two lines.

```
public List<Flurp> CreateFlurps(List<BadaBoom> badaBooms)
    {
        List<Flurp> flurps = new List<Flurp>();
        foreach (BadaBoom badaBoom in badaBooms)
        {
            flurps.Add(badaBoom .CreateFlurp());
            //or
            badaBoom.AddToListAsFlurp(flurps);
            //or
            flurps.Add(new Flurp(badaBoom));
            //or
            //make flurps a member of the class
            //use linq.Select()
            //etc
        }
        return flurps;
    }
```

or

```
foreach(var flurp in ConvertToFlurps(badaBooms))...
```

As noted by others, the advice that the best function is one with no arguments is skewed to OOP at best and plain bad advice at worst

Comment: Maybe you want to edit this answer to make it more clear? My question was if one thing outweighs another under Clean Code. You say that the whole thing is wrong and then go on to describe one of the options I gave. At the moment this answer looks like you are following an anti-Clean Code agenda instead of actually trying to answer the question.

Comment: sorry i interpreted your question as suggesting the first was the 'normal' way, but you were being pushed into the second. I'm not anti clean-code in general, but this quote is obviously wrong

Comment: @R.Schmitz I have read "Clean Code" myself, and I follow most of what that book says. However, concerning the perfect function size being pretty much a single statement, it's just plain wrong. The only effect is, that it turns spaghetti code into rice code. The reader is lost in the multitude of trivial functions that only produce sensible meaning when seen together. Humans have a limited working memory capacity, and you can either overload that with statements, or with functions. You must strike a balance between the two if you want to be readable. Avoid the extremes!

Comment: @cmaster The answer was only the first 2 paragraphs when i wrote that comment. It's a way better answer by now.

Comment: @R.Schmitz Ah, I didn't know that.

Comment: frankly I preferred my shorter answer. Theres too much diplomatic talk in most of these answers. The quoted advice is plain wrong, no need to speculate on 'what it really means' or twist around to try and find a good interpretation.

Comment: @cmaster Never heard the term "rice code" before, but it describes this perfectly well. Instead of 20 spaghetti you have 400 rice corns on your plate. (Maybe if you have really bad spahetti code that is full of holes you call it macaroni?)

Comment: heh 'monolith' could be a giant raviloli

Answer (score 15):

Second is definitely worse, as `CreateFlurpInList` accepts list and modifies that list, making the function not pure and harder to reason about. Nothing in the method name suggests the method only adds to the list.

And I offer third, best, option:

```
public List<Flurp> CreateFlurps(List<BadaBoom> badaBooms)
{
    return badaBooms.Select(CreateFlurp).ToList();
}
```

And hell, you can inline that method immediately if there is only one place where it is used, as the one-liner is clear by itself, so it doesn't need to be encapsulated by method to give it meaning.

Comment: I wouldm't complain so much about that method "not being pure and harder to reason about" (although true), but about it being a completely unnecessary method for handling a special case. What if I want to create a standalone Flurp, a Flurp added to an array, to a dictionary, a Flurp that then gets looked up in a dictionary and the matching  Flurp removed etc. ? With the same argument, the Flurp code would need all these methods as well.

Answer (score 10):

The one argument version is better, but not primarily because of the number of arguments.

The most important reason it is better is that it has **lower coupling**, which makes it more useful, easier to reason about, easier to test, and less likely to turn into copy+pasted clones.

If you provide me with a `CreateFlurp(BadaBoom)`, I can use that with any type of collection container: Simple `Flurp[]`, `List<Flurp>`, `LinkedList<Flurp>`, `Dictionary<Key, Flurp>`, and so on.  But with a `CreateFlurpInList(BadaBoom, List<Flurp>)`, I'm coming back to you tomorrow asking for `CreateFlurpInBindingList(BadaBoom, BindingList<Flurp>)` so that my viewmodel can get the notification that the list changed.  Yuck!

As an additional benefit, the simpler signature is more likely to fit with existing APIs.  You say you have a recurring problem

> rather often I find myself creating a list from another list

It's just a matter of using the tools available.  The shortest, most efficient, and best version is:

```
var Flurps = badaBooms.ConvertAll(CreateFlurp);
```

Not only is this less code for you to write and test, it's also faster, because `List<T>.ConvertAll()` is smart enough to know that the result will have the same number of items as the input, and preallocate the result list to the correct size.  While your code (both versions) required growing the list.

Comment: Don't use `List.ConvertAll`. The idiomatic way to map an enumerable of objects to different objects in C# is called `Select`.  The only reason `ConvertAll` is even available here is because the OP is erroneously asking for a `List` in the method -- it should be an `IEnumerable`.

Answer (score 6):

Keep the overall goal in mind: making the code easy to read and maintain.

Often, it will be possible to group multiple lines into a single, meaningful function. Do so in these cases. Occasionally, you'll need to reconsider your general approach.

For example, in your case, replacing the whole implementation with

```
var flups = badaBooms.Select(bb => new Flurp(bb));
```

might be a possibility. Or you might do something like

```
flups.Add(new Flurp(badaBoom))
```

Sometimes, the cleanest and most readable solution will simply not fit in one line. So you'll have two lines. Don't make the code harder to understand, just to fulfill some arbitrary rule.

Your second example is (in my opinion) considerably harder to understand than the first. It's not just that you have a second parameter, it's that the parameter is modified by the function. Look up what Clean Code has to say about that. (Don't have the book at hand right now, but I'm pretty sure it's basically "don't do that if you can avoid it").